# Cordova 5 VS 2015. Android App Can Not Create Folder

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I Updated to VS 2015 and Cordova 5. Since then i cannot create any folders or files anymore when using android.

There no errors thrown or anything what can help me solving this problem.

I am trying this:

```
      function onDeviceReady() {

         window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail); 

    }

    function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getDirectory("mynewfolder", { create: true }, gotDir, fail);
        console.log(fileSystem.root);

    }

    function gotDir(dirEntry) {
        dirEntry.getFile("myfile.txt", { create: true, exclusive: true }, gotFile, fail);
    }

    function gotFile(fileEntry) {
        // Do something with fileEntry here
    }

    function fail(error) {
        console.log(error.code);
    }
```

It say's all fine and folder is created but it's not. Any help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem ist that adding the plugins via VS2015 not working correctly. Had to add them via CLI

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to use [cordova file plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file). It allows you to manipulate paths and folders, and it prevents errors in different versions of OS or cordova.

Comment: I am using this plugin. Is there a wrong usage of this plugin?

Comment: I am using in cordova 5 and I have no problems. In which path are you trying to create the folder? Do you ask for the permissions? are you trying in a real device or simulator?

Comment: On Device. I want to have it in the  root directory.

Comment: I added the plugins via vs2015 so i guess there are all permissions which i need.

Comment: May it possible that i just cant see the files but they are acutally created?`

Comment: I checked this. I can read file via js but i just can not find it on my device

Comment: Well yeah this problem, but i need to acces these files via my computer^^

Comment: Computer OS? Windows? Try from console with `adb pull` maybe your file explorer had a weird cache or something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90813/discussion-between-markus-de-hh-and-del).